# Do some smtp servers refuse to SEND to a spam-blacklisted host?

Tags: email, smtp, spam

Is it known that some mail admins or mail programs setup their server like this? Is this a small minority? I don't have any examples, but i'm just curious.

Comment: It makes some sense to reject messages to sites/domains unable to reply (due to incoming blocks).

Comment: That makes only *some* sense indeed, because it's not their responsibility.